# Issue with cs50's IDE when compiling a program

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote a very simple program in cs50 IDE in Cloud9 and compiler yells at me an error message. The same program compiles and runs in Code blocks without a problem.

[[image: Any suggestions?]]

Comment: `%zu` instead of `%i`

Comment: Please post the code here..., as a `code`

Comment: try replacing %i with %lu, you are trying to print unsigned long as int(the error messages are very helpfl here, they have even pointed you to use %lu)

Comment: It would be better to ask cs50 related questions in dedicated stackexchange portal. https://cs50.stackexchange.com

Comment: I didn't know there was a whole section for cs50 in stackexchange. I will post my question there too. Thanks!

Comment: @Danh I'm not going to write out the posters code for them when they can just copy and paste it.

Comment: @Danh the URL you provided doesn't change anything, in fact it doesn't even show the image

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` operator return a `size_t` value.

Use the format `%zu`

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: It worked! But why CodeBlocks prints the size of data types using %i and not %zu?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Take your time to learn it before hurt yourself.